# Retention on Kafka Streams > 2.10

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I am joining to KStreams thus I need to set *JoinWindows*. The joined data has computed Timestamps from *CustomTimestampExtractors*. The Data could be out of order. I can set the *retention* with the deprecated `JoinWindows.until(long)`-method but since its deprecated I am looking for another solution.

I found the **windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms**-property am I supposed to use it ? This would lead to all state stores being retained that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Documentation states:

> Use [JoinWindows#grace(Duration)](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#grace-java.time.Duration-) instead

IMHO the doc is a bit misleading in contrast [to](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#until-long-):

> Set the window maintain duration (retention time) in milliseconds. This retention time is a guaranteed lower bound for how long a window will be maintained.

But be careful I wanted my StateStore to retain as long as possible thus I was using `JoinWindows.until(Long.MAX_VALUE)` before. Using `JoinWindows.grace(Duration.ofMillis(Long.Max_VALUE))` does complain that *grace period* can't be negative. There for you have to use smaller values.

Comment: Seems to be an limitation with `Duration` type -- but if you would just set `Duration.ofYears(100L)` it should be effectively unlimited :)